# GooglePlaces iOS, Can't load search results

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

GooglePlaces GMSAutocompleteViewController stopped searching for places.
[image: check the screenshot image]

GMSPlacesClient key is setup properly, It was working fine.

Please help if you know anything about this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

your Google places Key will be expire or you are inserting wrong key. please check your Key

```
import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

// TODO: Add a button to Main.storyboard to invoke onLaunchClicked:

// Present the autocomplete view controller when the button is pressed.
- (IBAction)onLaunchClicked:(id)sender {
  GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
  acController.delegate = self;
  [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Handle the user's selection.
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
    didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
    // Do something with the selected place.
    NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
    NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
    NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
    didFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    NSLog(@"error: %ld", [error code]);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

// User canceled the operation.
- (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
  NSLog(@"Autocomplete was cancelled.");
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

visit
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue.
I make google API key on my credit card added account. but that key not working properly. 
For resolve, this issue please **updates your pods**.